# Getting Exception Invalid object name 'MULTIPLE_OPERATIONS' while running the tridion 2013 upgrade database script

Tags: 2013-sp1, upgrade, database, installation

While running the tridion upgrade script, I am getting below exception.

```
Invoke-MsSqlScript : Failed to execute query: Invalid object name 'MULTIPLE_OPERATIONS'.
Query: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MULTIPLE_OPERATIONS
At F:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\MSSQL\Upgrade\61_70\Upgrade Content Manager database_61_70.ps1:15 char:6
+ if ((Invoke-MsSqlScript ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MULTIPLE_OPERATIONS")) -ne 0) {
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Tridion.Databas...eMsSqlUtilities:DatabaseMsSqlUtilities) [Invoke-MsS
   qlScript], DatabaseExecuteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DatabaseUtilitiesErrorId,Tridion.Database.Management.InvokeMsSqlScriptCommand
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your current Version?

Comment: Current version Tridion 2011

Answer (score 4):

From the error message it seems like it cannot find the object `MULTIPLE_OPERATIONS` object in database. It is a table in Tridion 2011 SP1 database, from the log it looks like it is failing in the step trying to upgrade from 2011SP1 database. Please ensure that the database is not corrupt or not missing any tables/sps or an earlier partial upgrade was not done on it.